Results from custom function using getValues and setValues when transferring data to external spreadsheet, often results in ERROR
I have a custom Apps Script function below. There is a range of tables stacked on top of each other containing employee performance information. when the range is selected, it is supposed to search the active range for a table containing employee performance information, and send it to their personal sheet with a unique link. The function works well, and takes the formatting and most of the values.
function updateCaliber(cycle) {
  const nameArray = getValuesFromRange();
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getActiveRange();

  spreadsheet.toast("Update started... This can take up to 3 seconds per employee. Confirmation message will show when complete .");

  nameArray.forEach(name => {
    const url = getUrl(name);
    if (!isEmpty(url)) {
      const targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
      const destSheet = targetSS.getSheetByName(name);
      const nameFinder = range.createTextFinder(name);
      const result = nameFinder.findNext();
      
      if (result) {
        const row = result.getRow();
        const col = result.getColumn();
        const caliberSheetRange = sheet.getRange(row, col - 1, sheetSizeX, sheetSizeY);
        const caliberValues = caliberSheetRange.getDisplayValues() // to get face values
        const caliberFormats = caliberSheetRange.getNumberFormats();
        const caliberRTV = caliberSheetRange.getRichTextValues();
        const caliberBG = caliberSheetRange.getBackgrounds();
        const caliberBGO = caliberSheetRange.getBackgroundObjects();
        const destRows = caliberSheetRange.getNumRows();
        const destCols = caliberSheetRange.getNumColumns();
        const pasteRange = destSheet.getRange(((cycle - 1) * (destRows + 1)) + 1, 1, sheetSizeX, sheetSizeY);
        const deadRange = destSheet.getRange(((cycle - 1) * (destRows + 1)) + 1, sheetSizeY - 1, 10, 2);

        pasteRange.setBackgrounds(caliberBG);
        pasteRange.setBackgroundObjects(caliberBGO);
        pasteRange.setNumberFormats(caliberFormats);
        pasteRange.setRichTextValues(caliberRTV);
        pasteRange.setBorder(true, true, true, true, false, false, null, SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
        pasteRange.setBorder(null, null, null, null, true, true, null, SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
        deadRange.setBorder(false, true, true, false, false, false, null, SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
        pasteRange.setValues(caliberValues); // Set values without recalculating formulas

        destSheet.autoResizeColumns(1, 2);
        destSheet.autoResizeColumns(4, sheetSizeY - 3);
      }
    }
  });

  Browser.msgBox("Update Complete!\\n\\nHOORAH!");
}

The problem is that for a select few of the sheet (about 45% of them) the function takes the formatting for the employee, but some of the values result in "#ERROR!" or "Loading..." when pulling values from cells that perform math based functions within the sheet. Ultimately I just want to take the display values, so no math should be performed when this function executes. There might be something I'm missing as far as intersheet operations go, but it's bizzarre that this problem doesn'y affect every employee.
I've attached before and after snippets of a section of sheet that gave unexpected results when transferring the data. I don't know if its a logic or syntax error, or something else entirely. Any insight is appreciated.


